# How should we qualify the [HTC]-tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

On Stack Overflow there is this [htc](/questions/tagged/htc) tag, already both in use for the [smartphone brand](http://www.htc.com/www/) as for the [File Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531018%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), yet undefined in the wiki.

IMHO, it should be assigned to the File Extension, but then the the tag would be wrong on all other questions already assigned to.

What is the best way to deal with this **specific** tag?

Update: the tag-wiki entry is accepted. The above information is for reference only.

Comment: please use `[tag:tagname]` markup when referring to tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like the idea of one tag having multiple meanings, then it seems the best course of action is to use [html-components](/questions/tagged/html-components) to refer to the file extension. That tag is *already being used* for this purpose (by a few questions), and according to the MSDN article you linked, that's the full version of the name:

> For Microsoft Internet Explorer 5 and later, HTML Components (HTCs) provide a mechanism to implement components in script as Dynamic HTML (DHTML) behaviors.

There's not much of an alternative for the smartphone brand, as HTC is now the official name of the company. It looks like [it used to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Corporation) "High Tech Computer Corporation", but they've dropped that. It's hard to imagine a better name for that tag.

Comment: So I have some work to do and retag all the appropriate HTC's to html-components, and update the HTC-tag-Wiki?

Comment: @Caspar: I mean, I assume so. There's no magical way to solve the problem. You can't create a tag synonym, or have a moderator merge the tags, since [tag:HTC] is currently applied to different types of questions. Someone is going to have to go in by hand and figure out which questions actually should have which tags.

Comment: I have no problems with that ;)